# ToolTip in SpecificText inside RichTextBox using MouseOver

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

im working on a code-editor and im just wondering how to make tooltip in text since its usually on tools in c# with a mouseover functionality . something like this:

[image]

sample senario,

when i type "abc" in richtextbox and mouseover it ToolTip with a Message "this is an alphabet" will appear .
same as with "123" inputted in richtextbox and get mouseover "this is a number will appear" .

is there anyway i can do that? without flooding or using any keypress? just mouseover in text? thanks a lot really need a help .

Comment: Windows Forms sir ...

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code:

```
 private void richTextBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double x;


            if (double.TryParse(richTextBox1.Text, out x))
            {
                toolTip1.Show(this is a number will appear",richTextBox1);

            }
            else
            {
                toolTip1.Show("this is an alphabet",richTextBox1);
            }

        }
```

Comment: doesnt work sir ... to tell you honestly i need to do it with c# events and keywords like in actual editor .

Comment: @user2234790 its work for me then only i post it. k Set the break point in if condition then check it. it correctly run or not. Any you are type the text in run time ah?